# What happens when I use Feast on the Fallen on Bloodcrazed Hoplite?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Me and a friend were playing magic, and I cast the enchantment [Feast on the Fallen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Feast%20on%20the%20Fallen), I dealt 3 damage with [Jagwasp Swarm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jagwasp%20Swarm). Then at the beginning of his upkeep I put 2 +1/+1 counters on [Bloodcrazed Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bloodcrazed%20Hoplite) saying its heroic ability allows it to get a second counter because it's being target by a spell that I control.

Comment: :( dang... that sucks.

Comment: It does, but the silver lining is that aura's do trigger heroic despite the lack of the word "target" on the card.